# Android Determine GPS status from kernel module

Tags: android, gps, linux-kernel, driver

I know that devices manufactures don't expose the source code of the drivers and low level components that communicate with the GPS hardware.
I wanted to ask if there any way to determent whether the GPS component is enabled/disabled from a kernel module without the need to use java API?

thank you

Comment: Why do you need to know this in a kernel module?

Comment: i want to be able to inform the user from the lowest level that his GPS receiver is on or off

Comment: But you won't be able to inform the user directly from a kernel module.

Comment: i can print messages to the kernel log file and inform him

Comment: Sadly the society of StackOverflow doesn't know too much about hardware or low-level software. I've asked many questions like this but none of them is answered well.